# PHP rename() works in terminal but not on server

Tags: php, rename

I have a php file on my apache2 server (var/www/html):

```
<?php
    $filename = "/var/www/html/test1.txt";
    $filename2 = $filename . ".old";
    rename($filename, $filename2);
?>
```

If I execute this script into terminal, it works, but if I load the same script into my browser nothing happens. Is this a permission issue?

Thanks for help

Comment: What is the return value of the `rename` function call?

Comment: jep. it is. check file ownership with ls -l, the webserver usually runs as `www-data`

Comment: Ownership is my user and the rename function returns 1 in terminal, but nothing in my browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is most certainly a permission's issue. Assuming you're a beginner I recommend the *whoring-out* technique.

```
~$ sudo chmod 777 -R /var/www/html
```

Comment: did that before your answer but not help

Comment: Are you sure the script is even executing in the first place?

Comment: what do you mean with first place?

Comment: give only the file the permission not the directory, now it works thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

try to use

**move_uploaded_file** instead rename.

Comment: Are you sure about 0777 permissions at file - and about permissions at directory where you want to place new file?

Comment: found the issue thanks, i also have to give the html folder chmod 777 or it will not work